# How to reduce the bit size of hexadecimal number in Perl

Tags: perl

This is the `64 bit size of [63:0]` hex number

```
0B08000000F41011
```

I want to reduce the above variable into `56 bit size of [55:0]` in perl without corrupting the original hex data. Can some body help me on this how to acheive this?

Answer (score 3):

This should not be possible for a simple reason:

64bit means that there are 18,446,744,073,709,551,616 possible states.

56bit means that there are 72,057,594,037,927,936 possible states.

The number you provided exceeds 56bit so it would lead to an overflow/cut-off or something.

```
highest number for 64 bit
0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF = 18,446,744,073,709,551,615 

highest number for 56 bit
0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFF   =     72,057,594,037,927,935

your number
0xB08000000F41011 =     794,885,334,246,887,441
```

Comment: If the OP has fewer possible inputs than 2^56, then it's possible to encode the numbers into 2^56 states even if the numbers are larger than 2^56. (e.g. 2^100 can accurately be stored in a 64-bit floating point number.) In other words, the OP hasn't provided enough information to make a determination as to whether what he wants to do is possible or not.

Comment: @ikegami You are right. It might be possible when using more complex bit formats/layouts (e.g. fixed bit size exponent and offset/significant) but the demanded precision has to be known to consider such options. Another possible approach could be found with splitting the 64bit input into two 56bit numbers (low bytes/high bytes). As you already stated we can't go on without a usecase/additional info from the OP.

Answer (score 2):

If for some reason the least significant eight bits of the upper 32 bits of this 64-bit value are always supposed to be zero, you can easily do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl;

use strict;
use warnings;

use bigint; # for portability

my $x = hex '0B08000000F41011';
my $lo = $x & 0xffffffff;
my $hi = $x >> 40;
my $y = ($hi << 32) | $lo;

printf "%16X\n", $_ for $x, $hi, $lo, $y;
```

Going back to `$x` given `$y` is left as an exercise.

Output:

```
 B08000000F41011
           B0800
          F41011
   B080000F41011
```